# How to show $P(B|A) \geq P(B) \Rightarrow P(B|\lnot A) \leq P(B)$ for binary random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am tasked with proving the following implication:

$$P(B|A) \geq P(B) \Rightarrow P(B|\lnot A) \leq P(B)$$

$A$, $B$ are binary random variables. I have tried deriving $P(B|\neg A)$ from $P(B|A)$ but I don't quite make it. Further I am only allowed to use a limited set of operations (definitions of total probability, bayes rule and conditional probability).

Does anyone have a tip on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Use the fact that $P(B) = P(B|A)P(A) + P(B|\neg A)(1-P(A))$

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that as well, but I am still stuck on the next few steps. Would I transform this into an inequality by substituting $P(B|A)$ with $P(B)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go straightforward as fallow :

from definition of conditional probability we have : $P(B|A) \geq P(B) \rightarrow P(A\cap B) \geq P(A)P(B). $ add $P(B) $ to both side $ P(B)-P(A)P(B) \geq P(B)-P(A\cap B) \Rightarrow P(B)P(A^{\prime}) \geq P(B\cap A^{\prime})  $ divide both side to $P(A^{\prime}) \Rightarrow P(B) \geq \frac{P(B\cap A^{\prime})}{P(A^{\prime})} = P(B|\lnot A) $ and this is what we want.